# Sticky notes are not sticky - How to avoid it?

Tags: stationery, paper

We brought the sticky notes box 3 years before and we left the room untouched. Now when we thought of using those stationery items, we thought we might use the sticky notes for my new office.

But to my surprise, the sticky notes are not sticky anymore. they have been glued and tearing it down damages the paper instead of the sticky surface.

What might be the problem? There was good air circulation going on before?

Comment: Try removing sticky notes (Post-it™) by peeling them from the side rather than vertically.

Comment: Are they expensive? If the glue has dried over 3 years then get some more.

Comment: Don't give up. Try contacting the manufacturer. Often, the item(s) will be replaced or reimbursed out of good will. Although/unless the item has a 'best-before' expiration indication, three years is not an unreasonable storage shelf-life for stationery. No-name brands occasionally suffer from production variations resulting in not-as-advertised performance.

Comment: @Stan It is not Post-it™ brand. Some Indian brand, everytime i try to peel, it looks like glue has dried out and thus resulting in paper jam.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not super expensive, but yea, we purchased a box, so only worrying.

Answer (score 1):

Buy smaller amounts of sticky notes, or pool funds together with someone else to buy a large quantity then split them. That way they will not go bad before you run out.

If you have old non-sticky sticky notes, use one of the old sticky notes together with a new sticky note. Write on them both (allows you to write extra long notes!) and then use the sticking power of the new note to stick them both on.

Or use them to make unit origami! :-)

[image: Sticky note icosahedron]